# QGraphicsView with ~500 items causing rest of UI to lag

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qgraphicsview

As the title says, in a program I'm making I have a `QGraphicsView` that contains a lot of items, about half of which are pixmaps. Obviously this is resource intensive, and I can't expect the display to update at 60 fps like I would prefer. That's fine, but it's important that the rest of the widgets perform crisply. Is there a way to render a `QGraphicsView` in a separate thread, or otherwise update it synchronously so it doesn't block my other widgets?

EDIT - Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHDKI.jpg

Comment: Threading won't help, as QGraphicsView isn't thread-safe. 500 items shouldn't be a problem in general though. Add more details on those items (e.g. size, how many are visible at once) and how they're updated (if they are).

Comment: The items are thumbnails that represent objects in another process that my program attaches to. The other process runs at 60 fps, so I sync the data at that frequency. Here's a screenshot, the QGraphicsView is in the lower tab: http://imgur.com/VzE0jWp

Comment: 500 items shouldn't be any problem (check out the 40000 chips demo). Have you looked at the various performance related properties of QGV?

Comment: 60 fps for a view like this sounds a bit high to me. did you check if reducing the update rate has any noticeable effect? I'd also check what the updating code does and if it could be optimized.